# How to combine array elements based on certain similar value?

Tags: php

I have an array that contain thousands elements. I need to merge elements that have the same certain part of the value.

```
$A = array('a|b|c','d|e|f','h|i|c','k|l|m');
```

I want to combine $A[0] with $A[2] because both contain "c". So the new array becomes:

```
$A = array('a|b|c|h|i','d|e|f','k|l|m');
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please ignore my edit attempt, I misread your question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An uncomplicated solution:

```
$A = array('a|b|c','d|e|f','h|i|c','k|l|m');

$B = array();
foreach($A as $v) {
    $B[] = explode("|", $v);
}

$i = 0;
$count = count($B);
while($i < $count-1) {
    for ($j = ($i+1); $j < $count; $j++) {
        if (!isset($B[$j])) {
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($B[$j] as $v) {
            if (in_array($v, $B[$i])) {
                $B[$i] = array_unique(array_merge($B[$i], $B[$j]));
                unset($B[$j]);
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }
    $i++;
}

$C = array();
foreach ($B as $v) {
    sort($v);
    $C[] = implode("|", $v);
}

print_r($C);
```

Gives you

```
Array ( [0] => a|b|c|h|i [1] => d|e|f [2] => k|l|m )
```

First we split the original $A array into an array of arrays (so we can use in_array later), then loop through our new array of arrays $B, looping through all inner elements combining if there's a match and removing that later element. Because arrays in PHP are associate, once we remove B[2], it'll leave B[3] as is, so we have to have a check to make sure $B[$j] is actually still part of our array, else we'll hit an error.